# Apache/php won't run a shell scrpit

Tags: php, permissions, copy, apache2, local

Using Ubuntu 20.04.

I want to copy this file:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 197801 Jan 15 17:33 /home/user/programming/masterFile
```

to:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 14 12:27 html
```

The script is:

```
sudo -u user -p password cp /home/userprogramming/masterFile /var/www/html/masterFile
```

I have tried using exec(), system(), passthru() both putting the command in the function or calling the script with the command inside it.

I added this line to apache2.conf

```
<Directory /home/user/programming>
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't use PHP's [copy()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function?

Comment: Does the script work? Has the script the executable flag? Who is the owner of the script? Does it require some sort of input from the user? I see you're passing a password: why not avoid it creating a specific entry in the sudoers file (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt)?

Comment: Tried the copy() function returns "failed to open stream: Permission denied in".  Yes the script works and it does run when using PHP from the command line however not from the browser. This is the owner and permissions on the script itself "-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data".

Comment: I got it to work. I moved the directory "programming" to root and then from the home folder made a soft link to it.  Now the file can be copied using my php script with apache.